# Equivalent of pchisq and qchisq of python giving different response

Tags: python

Trying to convert R code to python - but the answers are difference - how to get the correct answer.

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np

w=0.1
df=(5-1)*(6-1)
power=0.80
sig_level=0.05
N=2096

k = stats.chi2.ppf(1 - sig_level, df=df)
stats.chi2.cdf(k, df=df, loc=0, scale=N * np.square(w))

#7.794689867277589e-09


df=(5-1)*(6-1)
N=2096
sig.level=0.05
w=0.1
k <- qchisq(sig.level, df = df, lower.tail = FALSE)
pchisq(k, df = df, ncp = N * w^2, lower.tail = FALSE)

#0.799980333167868
```